# Lightning Framework - fire events

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In the Lightning Component framework, which third party resource can be used to fire events - Third-party web service code or Third -party Javascript code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firing events can only be wired up by the Lightning lifecycle.  That means anything outside the context of the actual lightning DOM cannot fire those events, so no third party web service code.

The third party javascript code is a different story.  The lightning documentation says that you can only register/fire events from built-in resources such as components or related controllers/helpers.

It appears you probably want to write a wrapper function in your component which will call the third party code and fire the event when done.

You can find more at the [lightning developer's guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/lightning.pdf) on page 136.